# Custom Kivy widget callbacks

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I want to make a numpad in Kivy and be able to read the value entered in the numpad and attach a function to something like `on_submit`.

My class looks like this

```
class NumPad(Widget):
    field = ObjectProperty()
    def validate(self):
        # RULL CUSTOM CALLBACK HERE
```

and my Kivy file looks like this

```
<NumPad>:
    field: field
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            name: 'field'
        GridLayout:
            cols: 3
            Button: # REPEAT 9 TIMES
                text: '1'
                on_press: root.field.text += '1'
            Button: 
                text: 'del'
                on_press: root.field.text = ''
            Button:
                text: '0'
                on_press: root.field.text += '0'
            Button:
                text: 'enter'
                on_press: root.enter()
```

and is it then possible to define it like this?

```
<Root>:
    BoxLayout:
        NumPad:
            on_enter: # DEFINE CODE TO BE CALLED!
```

So it runs the code that's defined on a widget instance basis? 
Thanks!

Comment: Yes you can use 'register_event_type' method as described here: https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.event.html?highlight=event#kivy.event.EventDispatcher.register_event_type

Comment: Thanks!! It took me a bit to understand that the `on_press:` in Kivy lang is just an alias for `widget.bind('on_press'..` but once that clicked (or pressed, amiright?!) I got it, thanks :)